# Blacklisting IP Address

Tags: php, ip, blacklist

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != 'xx.xx.xx.xx') { 
header("Location: http://google.com");
} ?>
```

Is this a good way to block certain IP addresses from accessing some folders on my windows server ?

Or it can be intercepted with proxy softwares like webscarab and the originating IP address could be modified to bypass this ?

Comment: Friendly reminder: don't forget to accept a good answer by clicking on the checkbox next to the answer.  You can go back and do this on your old questions as well, which will help others find solutions more quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can bypassed with any proxy with has a different IP address to the one you are blocking. You could check `X-Forwarded-For` (dig it out with `apache_request_headers()` *if* you are using Apache), but this is much easier to spoof if you give it precedence over `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

Also, I could ignore your `Location` header. Put an `exit` after it as well.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply alex. But would you suggest as a software or an alternative to htaccess that i can use on IIS 7.5 ?

Comment: @PHPBeginner Sorry, I forgot you were using IIS. Doing it in PHP is fine, so long as you do it right. Also, are you trying to stop access to the server doing a directory listing? I'm sure that could be disabled via IIS config.

Comment: I'm giving login access to some people i trust. So i'm whitelisting their IP Address using this script.

Comment: This actually *does* look like a whitelist to me.

Comment: So, is it ok if i use it ? Or there's a security flaw behind it. And i'm sorry if i go a little off-topic. Alex, Why is it different if I have Apache installed for example. Is this an apache exploit ? Excuse me but i'm still a begginer.

Comment: @PHPBeginner I mentioned that because I suggested using `apache_request_headers()` which is irrelevant if using IIS :)

Comment: Not only X-Forwarded-For, but also a dozen of headers may contain real IP: `HTTP_VIA`, `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, `HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR`, `HTTP_X_FORWARDED`, `HTTP_FORWARDED`, `HTTP_CLIENT_IP`, `HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR_IP`, `VIA`, `X_FORWARDED_FOR`, `FORWARDED_FOR`, `X_FORWARDED`, `FORWARDED`, `CLIENT_IP`, `FORWARDED_FOR_IP`, `HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION`

Comment: @Nemoden That's quite a list :)

Comment: Alright. Bottom-line is ? Should I use an htaccess alternative ? and If so, What is it ? Thank you again for your replies.

Comment: @PHPBeginner I haven't used IIS in about 10 years so I'm not sure what it would be sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If your are want only blocking by IP you can use .htaccess for that - it's more easy to set rule for set of directories instead of creating a lot of php files. But it's not a good method for filter users. Create a simple registration form, or use API from twitter, facebook or another.